# react native toaster (react-native-easy-toast) only displays once

Tags: react-native

I have a button that when clicked it shows a toaster until something happens that either closes it or displays another one with an error message.

It works fine the first time I load the screen but if I press the button again the initial toast doesn't show. The error toast does show after a few seconds (assuming there is an error). The only difference between these two is that the initial one has a duration.forever. Also since it stays forever I'm using a toast.close to stop displaying it.

I even decided to make two components one for the initial and one for the error but same thing happens.

Component that has toast code

```
showToast(text){
   this.refs.toast.show(text);
}

showToastForever(text) {
   this.refs.toast.show(text, DURATION.FOREVER);
}

closeToast(){
   this.refs.toast.close();
}

render(){
   return(
      <Toast ref="toast"
      style={{backgroundColor: 'black'}}
      position='bottom'
      positionValue={150}
      />
   )
}
```

Component that extends the code above

```
displayToast(text){
   if(text == 'detecting location...'){
      this.showToastForever(text)
   } else{
        this.closeToast()
        this.showToast(text)
   }
}

hideToast(){
   this.closeToast()
}

myRender(){
   return(
      <View>
         <SearchLocation
         callbackToaster={ this.displayToast }
         callbackHide={ this.hideToast }
         />
      </View>
   )
}
```

SearchLocation

```
myRender(){
   return(
      <View>
         <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.checkLocation()}>
         //icon and styles
         </TouchableOpacity>

         //other irrelevant stuff

      </View>
   )
}

checkLocation(){
   this.props.callbackToaster('detecting location...')
   this.requestLocationPermission()
}

async requestLocationPermission() {
   if(!permission){
      //ask phone for permissions
   } else{
      this.getCurrentLocation();
   }
}

getCurrentLocation() {
   RNGooglePlaces.getCurrentPlace()
   .then((results) => {
      this.props.callbackHide()

      //other stuff about displaying results

   })
   .catch((error) => {
      this.props.callbackToaster('network unavailable')
   });
}
```

Comment: Try this package instead [rn-custom-toast](https://github.com/roundcubelabs/rn-custom-toast)